# Using reduce and skipping an array with 0 in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, math

I am getting a TypeError when using reduce on an empty array (`[]`).

I don't want to remove the 0 or anything like that I would rather reduce just return the 0 back to that array.

Here is my current code:

```
function squareSum(numbers) {

  let numList = numbers.map(x => Math.pow(x, 2));

  const sum = numList.reduce((x, y) => {
    return x + y
  }); 
  
  return sum;
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Reduce of an empty array with no initial value
```

Comment: That error only happens when the array is `[]`.

Comment: What are you passing as parameters to `squareSum` function?

Comment: @D.Pardal, exactly. This error occurs with an empty array.

Comment: your code works you just have to pass an array of numbers

Comment: @Sven.hig I have an array of numbers coming into the function, it was whenever the test hit a 0 is whenever the test failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an initial value as the second parameter of the `reduce` method.

If you omit the initial value i.e. the second parameter of the `reduce` then the reduce assumes the `array[0]` is the `y` of your `reduce` at the first iteration.

```
function squareSum(numbers) {

  let numList = numbers.map(x => Math.pow(x, 2));

  const sum = numList.reduce((x, y) => {
    return x + y
  }, 0); // Change here. Use zero initially
  
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Okay awesome, thank you! I didn't realize I also had to pass the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite clear. You did not provide the initial value of the accumulator as the second argument to [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), so it cannot produce a result when the array is empty.

```js
function squareSum(numbers){
  let numList = numbers.map(x => Math.pow(x, 2));
  const sum = numList.reduce((x, y) => {
    return x + y
  }, 0); //initial value set to 0
  return sum;
}
console.log(squareSum([]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function squareSum(numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce((a, x) => a + Math.pow(x, 2), 0); 
}

console.log(squareSum([]));
console.log(squareSum([0]));
console.log(squareSum([5]));
console.log(squareSum([1,2,3,4,5]));
```